# gradle test doesn't work well

Tags: gradle, dbunit

When I run test in IntelliJ, it works well, but if I run it by command line like

`gradle test` or `gradle clean test`

it rerurns `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
String FILE_PATH = "sample/src/test/resources/" 
IDataSet insertDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH + "com/sample/mst.xml"));
```

Project structure is:

TestProject

- sample

  - src

    - main
    - test

      - java

        - com

          - sample

            - test.java
      - resources

        - com

          - sample

            - mst.xml

What is wrong, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change file loading code to:

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mst.xml")`

Comment: Explanation is part of introductory courses on Java and a lot can be learned from Javadoc too. Short version: your attempt resolved the file using relative path from current working directory assuming what is it the CWD. The suggested solution searches for the resource on a classpath knowing that there is a hierarchical structure (usually filesystem or ZIP/JAR archive) and leaving details to runtime.